# UWP: How to get image height and width after the image is displayed on UI

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am loading and image from a IRandomAccessStream like this:

```
    private async void SetImageSourceToImage(IRandomAccessStream stream)
    {
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);

        myImage.Source = bitmapSource;
    }
```

And here is the XAML:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="AntiqueWhite">
            <Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            <InkCanvas x:Name="myInkCanvas"/>
            <InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind myInkCanvas}" />
        </Grid>
```

After the image is displayed on the screen, I want to take its `Height` and `Width` in order to set the Height and Width for an InkCanvas.

The issue is that after the image is displayed on the screen ActualWidth, ActualHeight, Height and Width properties of the myImage are 0 or NaN.

Indeed, there is `decoder.PixelWidth` and `decoder.PixelHeight` values, but I don't know if they help me, because I use `Stretch="Uniform"` in XAML.

Comment: Have you tried getting the actual width and height values in the ImageOpened event of the Image?

Comment: According to documentation, ImageOpened event occurs when the image source is downloaded and decoded with no failure. I was setting the image source for the Image element in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin said, we can get the actual width and height values in the ImageOpened event of the Image.

> You can check ActualHeight and ActualWidth at run time after the image renders to get the measurement information. Or, you can handle ImageOpened and check image file properties such as PixelHeight and PixelWidth immediately before the image renders.

For more info, please refer the [Image Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image).

When I add the [`Image.ImageOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_ImageOpened) event, it seems it does not be fired when I set the Source by the `Image.Source` in the `SetImageSourceToImage` method.

We can set the `BitmapImage` in the `Image.Source`, that we can add the `BitmapImage.ImageOpened` event of `BitmapImage`. It occurs when the BitmapImage source is setted with no failure.

For example:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage x:Name="imageSource" ImageOpened="imageSource_ImageOpened" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void imageSource_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(myImage.ActualHeight);
    Debug.WriteLine(myImage.ActualWidth);
}
```